# ./configure: error: the HTTP XSLT module requires the libxml2/libxslt libraries

Tags: nginx, libxml2, macos-mojave, libxslt

I recently updated my mac-os to Mojave. I was using Nginx and it was working on my previous os but after updating to Mojave, I am not able to start my Nginx.
So I tried to install it again, first, it gave me c compiler error, So I downloaded the Xcode command-line tools and it was gone. Now it gives me libxml2/libxslt libraries not found. I tried to install it using brew but I still get the same error. I am not sure what is going wrong.

I have downloaded libxml2 and libxslt using brew install.

My configure script.

```
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/nginx/$NGINX_NAME_VERSION \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/$NGINX_NAME_VERSION/conf/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/body \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/scgi \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi \
--with-debug \
--with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_geoip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_xslt_module \
--with-mail \
--with-mail_ssl_module \
--with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include \
--with-ld-opt=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \
--builddir=$NGINX_BUILD_PATH
```

Error :

```
checking for OpenSSL library ... found
checking for zlib library ... found
checking for libxslt ... not found
checking for libxslt in /usr/local/ ... not found
checking for libxslt in /usr/pkg/ ... not found
checking for libxslt in /opt/local/ ... not found
```

You can see it is able to find OpenSSL, zlib but not libxslt. Please someone help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 18):

Try the following

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
```

You might also need

```
sudo apt-get install libgd-dev # for the "error: the HTTP image filter module requires the GD library." error
sudo apt-get install libgeoip-dev # for the GeoIP package
```

Comment: On Fedora 33, this doesn't work. No such library. The usual `libxslt` is in fact installed, but Nginx still gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you know you have installed `libxslt` but nginx still keeps yelling you are not.

The actual problem behind is not about whether `libxslt` has been installed, is about can nginx successfully link to it. In the end, I discovered that `libxlst` links to an older version of `icu` installed on my environment. I then realize that my `libxml2` is too old. After upgrading my `libxml2`, everything works again.